# How to update ng-option value dynamically with another ng-option selected value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have 2 select option box in my app. First select option box contains the name of Countries. I want to update second select option box value with respect to value selected in first select box.

For example, If I select India, than second select box value should contain all states of India. Similar for other countries also but I am not able to do so.

Code:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="item as item for item in country">
    <option ng-if="!selectedCountry" value="">Select Country</option>
</select>
<pre>selectedItem: {{selectedItem | json}}</pre>

<select ng-model="selectedState" ng-options="{{selectedState}}">
    <option ng-if="!selectedState" value="">Select state</option>
</select>
<pre>selectedItem: {{selectedState | json}}</pre>
```

JS:

```
$scope.country = [
         "India",
         "America",
        "Nepal",
         "China"
    ];
  $scope.India = ["Bihar"];
    $scope.America = ["Arizona"];
    $scope.China = ["Beging"];
    $scope.Nepal = ["Dhankuta"];
```

Comment: Seems this questions was answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991960/using-jquery-how-do-i-filter-a-dropdown-field-based-on-value-selected-from-anoth

Comment: No. I want to do it with angular, not with jquery. Your link is not so useful.

Comment: My apologies, didn't see your tags.

Answer (score 4):

You can make your countries the keys of an array like `countries.india` etc In second Select you can set ng-options to repeat from the `countries` key that matches selected option of `selectedCountry` in first select box. like if India is selected that will repeat through key 'india' of `countries`  array

**Demo**

```js
angular.module('test', [])
.controller('testController', function($scope) {
    $scope.country = [
        "India",
        "America",
        "Nepal",
        "China"
    ];
    $scope.countries = [];
    $scope.countries.India = ["Bihar", "mumbai"];
    $scope.countries.America = ["Arizona"];
    $scope.countries.China = ["Beging"];
    $scope.countries.Nepal = ["Dhankuta"];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController">
  <select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="item as item for item in country">
      <option ng-if="!selectedCountry" value="">Select Country</option>
  </select>
  <pre>selectedItem: {{selectedCountry}}</pre>

  <select ng-model="selectedState" ng-options="items for items in countries[selectedCountry]">
      <option ng-if="!selectedCountry" value="">Select Country</option>
  </select>
  <pre>selectedItem: {{selectedState }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working. But select box is taking 2 empty value.

Comment: Thank You.. anyway I have also done the same changes.

Comment: surely.. I am waiting for some more answers. I will do it in some time. Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

you should use ng-change property of select.

```
<select ng-change="changeStates()">...</select>

$scope.changeStates = function(){
    $scope['currentStates'] = $scope[$scope.selectedCountry];
};

<select ng-options="state as state for state in currentStates">...</select>
```

but in my humble opinion you should better use id values

Edit: and you shouldn't inject States into scope directly. scope.States.America will be better

Comment: Thank you for answer. But i didn't get it properly. Can you give a fiddle example here.

Comment: Ya.. I am following your answer.

Comment: can you up-vote my question so that I can do the same with accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use the $watch function see the demo [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsikrishnamannem/yjm2mhhL/)

```
 <body ng-app ng-controller="AppCtrl"> <select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="item as item for item in country">
        <option value="">Select Country</option> </select> <pre>selectedItem: {{selectedCountry | json}}</pre>

    <select ng-model="selectedState" ng-options="item as item for item in state">
        <option ng-if="!selectedState" value="">Select state</option> </select> <pre>selectedItem: {{selectedState | json}}</pre> </body>
```

javascript:

```
function AppCtrl($scope) {

$scope.country = ["India", "America", "Nepal","China" ];
var state = {India :["Bihar"],America :["Arizona"],China:["Beging"],Nepal:["Dhankuta"]};
    $scope.$watch('selectedCountry', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if ( newValue) {
      $scope.state = state[$scope.selectedCountry];
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ng_developer, something difference means what type you want

Comment: I mean your answer is different in approach. I liked it.. Thank You